# Openpxyl problem with sheet names with spaces

Tags: openpyxl

I have an issue where if a sheet name has a space in it, it yields an error when trying to get the worksheet

````
```wb = load_workbook(excel_file, read_only=True, data_only=True)  
sheet_names = wb.get_sheet_names()```
````

sheet_names=
['TB Sep  19',
 '1000000000 - 1999999999',
 '2000000000 - 2999999999',
 '30000000000 - 4999999999',
 '5000000000-999999999',
 'Transaction Pivots',
 'TB Reconciliation']

`worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('1000000000 - 1999999999')` ok

`worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Transaction Pivots')` Error:'Worksheet Transaction Pivots does not exist.'

Comment: Are you sure that you are referencing the right workbook object? You have specified wb as your workbook, but you are getting the sheet from workbook.

Comment: will check this in the morning incase i have done something stupid or just confirm i pasted the wrong code into stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work. Was just being a numpty